# Unitary element in an AF $C^*$-algebra can be approximated by sequence of unitaries

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

Let $A$ be a unital AF $C^*$-algebra. 
Write $A=\overline{\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}A_k}$ where each $A_k$ is a unital (with the same unit of $A$) finite dimensional $C^*$ subalgebra. Suppose $u\in A$ is a unitary element.

I want to show that given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $u_k \in A_k$ unitary such that $||u-u_k||<\epsilon$.

I'm not sure that it is true, but if I could show the above claim then it helps me to conclude $K_1(A)$ is zero for A unital AF $C^*$-algebra.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow, after I post here a question the solution comes to my mind...

 So, I'll use the following argument:
[almost unitaries are close to a unitary element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850816/almost-unitaries-are-close-to-a-unitary-element/1851986)

 Now, it's enough to show that: 
If $A$ is a unital $C^*$ algebra and $A=\overline{\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} A_k}$ ,where each $A_k$ is a unital (same unit of $A$) $C^*$ subalgebra, then for any unitary $u\in A$ and any $\epsilon>0$ there exist $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and unitary $v\in A_n$ such that $||u-v||<\epsilon$.
(I dropped the assumption that each $A_n$ is f.d., it's not relevant).
So, for small enough $\delta>0$ (which depends on $\epsilon$), find $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a\in A_n$ s.t. $||a-u||<\delta$ and $||a||\leq 1$ (it is possible because the unit ball of the union is dense in the unit ball of $A$).
Now, $||a^*a-1||=||a^*a-a^*u+a^*u-u^*u||\leq ||a^*|| \ ||a-u||+||a^*-u^*|| \ ||u||\leq 2\delta$. 
Similarly, we can show $||aa^*-1||\leq 2\delta$. 
So, if $\delta$ small enough then $\exists v\in A_n$ unitary s.t. $||a-v||< {\epsilon\over 2}$. 
Consequently, $||v-u||<{\epsilon \over 2} +\delta<\epsilon$ (by requiring also $\delta<{\epsilon\over 2}$) , as desired.

Comment: This looks fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring your original question: Note that $A = \lim_k A_k$ so $K_1(A) = \lim_k K_1(A_k)$. But $K_1(A_k) = 0$ since $K_1(M_n(\mathbb C)) = 0$ for each natural number $n$. This is a general argument that AF algebras have trivial $K_1$-group.

Comment: Thanks! yes, this is the best way to do it, but I still haven't read about continuity of $K_1$ and tried to compute it directly...
I hope the answer I've posted now is OK.